# (Windows, Mac) How to load both XDebug & ionCube Loader simultaneously?

Tags: php, xdebug, ioncube

I am trying to load XDebug & ionCube loader simultaneously, when I type `zend_extension_ts="path/to/ioncube_loader_win_5.2.dll"` or `zend_extension_ts="path/to/php_xdebug.dll"` alone in php.ini they work. But I cant get them working simultaneously. Is there any way I can load them both ?

I was thinking if I can load them only for particular directory/project, I don't know if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have installed ionCube successfully on the top of Zend debugger without running into any issues,

To Install ionCube, I have downloaded the zip file for my OS from [here](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php)
then I ran the `localhost/ioncube/loader-wizard.php`, it will tell you step by step what to do, for me because I have windows and wamp server I had to insert the ioncube folder in

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\
```

here is the php version and explanation:

```
PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: Apr 30 2014 11:20:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

I saw in other stackoverflow post mentioned by [Arte Arefjev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819285/apache-stuck-with-working-after-xdebug-was-installed-ioncube-loader-error)  that the `zend_extention` of ioncube should be the first one to load so I did this:

```
zend_extension = "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/bin/ioncube/ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll"
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
```

all my debugger and at the same time my ioncube is working fabulous!

Hope it will help someone in the future.

Comment: you mentioned `I saw in other stackoverflow post `, it would be great if you can give link here.

Answer (score 7):

Xdebug is not compatible with ioncube: http://xdebug.org/docs/install#compat You can not have them both installed in the same server environment, so you'll have to set-up two server instances (or use lighttpd/nginx with two fast-cgi configurations) as I have described here: http://derickrethans.nl/multiple-php-versions.html

Answer (score 1):

For me it seems to work with php 5.3.10 as it says

```
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd., and
with Xdebug v2.2.0rc1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

but i havent tested debugging with files containing ioncube encoded content yet.